# Why do I get DONE after AUTH LOGIN command to SMTP Server?

Tags: email, ssl, certificate, smtp, openssl

I am trying to connect to my server SMTP on Windows 2012 R2 server on which is installed a RapidSSL 256 bit certificate. I need to test if the SMTP server can send email to one of our customers which seems to have problem with the certificate. They told me my certificate could not support new SHA256 cryptography but this is wrong. This is the command I launch:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect www.omniservice2.it:25 -crlf
```

and I get this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=www.omniservice2.it
i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=www.omniservice2.it
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3697 bytes and written 363 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : TLSv1
  Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
  Session-ID: ...
  Session-ID-ctx: 
  Master-Key: ...
Key-Arg   : None
Start Time: 1487243991
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 OK
```

Then I go with:

```
HELO

AUTH LOGIN
```

and I enter username/password encoded in base64. Credentials are correct and they are normal Windows authentication username/password and they are correctly used by all our .NET application to access the SMTP server.
So, credentials encoded in base64 are surely correct but after entering them, I am prompted DONE and the connection is closed and the shell returns.
What does this mean?

Here's the sequence of my commands:

```
>HELO
250 www.omniservice2.it Hello [37.159.171.6]
>AUTH LOGIN
>334 VNXlcm5hbWU6
(my Windows username encoded in base64)
>334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
(my Windows password encoded in base 64)
>DONE
>prompt returned here
```

If, after HELO, I send a `STARTTLS` command, it tells me there is an already started TLS Session.
As said, I would really need to directly connect and test that SMTP sever and discovers why it cannot deliver email to that unique customer. What coould be wrong with my certificate?

**UPDATE**

Here's what I've tried with PLAIN authentication mode, both using telnet and openssl:

```
telnet www.omniservice2.it 25
Trying 94.177.162.33...
Connected to www.omniservice2.it.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 www.omniservice2.it Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.5.9600.16384 ready at  Thu, 16 Feb 2017 16:28:00 +0100 
EHLO www.omniservice2.it
250-www.omniservice2.it Hello [37.159.171.6]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 4194304
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-TLS
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
AUTH PLAIN
Connection closed by foreign host.

MacBook-Pro-di-lorenzo:~ lory$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect www.omniservice2.it:25 -crlf
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=www.omniservice2.it
i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=www.omniservice2.it
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3697 bytes and written 363 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Session-ID: B61C00007D21763C94DBF1394AEC1B84768F4DAED89FC3BEC2E74A0321090A71
Session-ID-ctx: 
Master-Key: 829BFD1853358B1471837EDEAD068905D9652E7A33121BF6186BBC971F20DB5FBEC0658464DAC6040DD5FD9ACB3BA4AA
Key-Arg   : None
Start Time: 1487258920
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 OK
AUTH PLAIN
504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

Comment: Could be a bug in the server's `LOGIN` implementation. Have you tried using the standard `PLAIN` instead?

Comment: @grawity thank you for your kind comment but I'm a complete ignorant as 
System Engineer. What's PLAIN?

Comment: `PLAIN` is the [SASL PLAIN](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4616) mechanism. It's started similarly to LOGIN in your example, but expects a single message (null byte + username + null byte + password).

Comment: I'm having a trial but I'm afraid I cannot use AUTH PLAIN to login because it says "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type"

Comment: @grawity if you want have a look to my updated question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I banged my head against this problem for several days before finding out that openssl s_client interprets a Q character at the start of the password as a "quit" command and closes the connection.

If your password begins with a Q when base64-encoded, pass `-quiet` as a switch to the openssl s_client command and it will stop closing the connection.

Comment: Wow, that is great help!

Comment: Hahah, I can't believe this was the case. Indeed passing -quiet lead to "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful". Omg.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to put a single space char before the password.
In my case the Authentication get successfully.

Comment: +1 this also works